# context is not behaving properly in react. printing default values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I created below context in `react`.

`NameContext.tsx`

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
export  const AppContext = createContext("NA");
```

I used this context inside my `Layout.tsx` . I am using inside Layout because I have some business logic to execute. based on that `isActive` value will be set.

```
const [isActive,setIsActive]=useState("NO");
return(
    <AppContext.Provider value={isActive}>
             <User/>
     </AppContext.Provider> 
)
```

now under `User.tsx` I am accessing this tab.

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { AppContext } from "../context/NameContext";

const User = ()=>{

 const context = useContext(AppContext);
  let isActive:any;

 if(context=="YES")
  isActive=true;

  else
  isActive=false;

  console.log("context is:"+context);
  console.log(isActive);
  
    return(
        <>
                  <span>
                 {isActive && <Link to="user" > List of Users</Link> } 
                  </span>

          </>        

    )
}
export default User;
```

in just one page refresh it is delivering values many times and most of the time default values. I dont want default values but the value which I set in provider.
how can I avoid this abnormal behaviour.

[image]

Comment: The only way a context consumer sees the default value is if it's rendered ***outside*** a context provider. I am unable to reproduce the issue you see with your code copy/pasted into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/context-is-not-behaving-properly-in-react-printing-default-values-xghhj4). Are you rendering another `User` component elsewhere? Outside the provider?

Comment: Thank you Drew. can it be the case my consumer is displaying value even before provider has set the value? thats why it is diaplying default value. I mean can it be the case?

Comment: No, I don't think so. `isActive` has initial state value `"NO"` and that is what is used on the initial render. A parent component (*a.k.a. the `Provider`*) starts its render cycle *before* its children's (*a.k.a. the a consumer*), and completes its render cycle *after* all children have completed rendering.

Comment: It worked Drew. I was doing other mistake and this functionality was getting break. thank you so much for your kind help.

Comment: I see. Is this question unreproducible and should be closed then?

Comment: ya Drew...But I am not able to delete because people already answered and put effort. stackoverflow not allowing me to delete.

Answer (score 1):

create a wrapper then put the Layout inside the Wrapper component, the value will be available globally.

```
//Wrapper
 import React, { useState } from "react";
 export const Context = React.createContext();
 const Wrapper = (props) => {
 const [active, setActive] = useState('NO');
 function changeValue(value) {
  setActive(value)
  }
 function getCurrent() {
   return active;
  }
return (
<Context.Provider value={{ active, changeValue, getCurrent }}>
    {props.children}
</Context.Provider>
);
};

export default Wrapper;

// index.tsx
import Wrapper from './path/Wrapper'
<Wrapper>
  <App />
</Wrapper>

//Layout must be inside App!
//Layout.tsx
import { Context } from "../../layout/Wrapper";
export default function Layout(){
  const context = useContext(Context);
  console.log(context.getCurrent()) // NO
  context.changeValue('YES')
  console.log(context.getCurrent()) // YES
}
```